# Одиночное деепричастие как наречие?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастия, разговорная-речь

Наведение мостов после длительного молчания начиналось так:

> N: «Добрый день, S!».
>
> S: «Что скажешь смотря».

(Корявый ответ с подтекстом — может быть, день и будет добрым.) Ошибся ли, не отделив деепричастие?

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что нет, не ошиблись.

[**смотря кто**](https://orthography.academic.ru/31483) (***что**, как, где, когда, какой, зачем* и т. п.) [Б. З. Букчина]
Обозначает зависимость выбора от того, на что указывает местоименное слово:
**— Ты любишь гулять?

— Смотря где.**

В словаре Ушакова:
[СМОТРЕ́ТЬ](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1031506)
**17.** *Деепричастие* **смотря́** в сочетании с наречиями и относительными местоимениями употребляется в значении ***в зависимости от того**.* *Смотря где итти. Смотря какой человек. Смотря как жить. **Смотря что купить.***
[Итти — так в словаре (1935–1940).]

> — Погоди! — встрепенулся Темняк. — Сейчас… Дай опомниться. И далеко это?
> — Смотря как считать. Если напрямик, то близко. А плутая, далеко.
> [Ю. Брайдер. Н. Чадович. Хозяева Острога](http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=33958&p=64)

Порядок слов в Вашем разговорном высказывании, конечно, нестандартный (не знаю, можно ли назвать его инверсией), но сути, считаю, не меняет — деепричастие запятой отделять не нужно.

[Смотря(,) где / как / кто...](http://old-punctum.ru/punctum.php?sid=686)

Comment: Спасибо. «В зависимости от того» — то, что надо. Только в случае изнанки аналог на ум не приходит.

Comment: И Вам "вельми понеже"! /// Удивительно: в разговорной речи мы часто изменяем-переворачиваем-искручиваем стандартные выражения — и даже не замечаем этого. Но как только мы их видим воочию (вчитываемся, оцениваем), сразу наступает растерянность. Как же — разве мы так говорим?! Оказывается — да, говорим. Не всегда, не везде, но — говорим.